# Schematic shows some resistor values as DNE

Tags: resistors, pcb-design, schematics

What does it mean on a schematic when some resistor values are listed as DNE?

Comment: It's probably a 'Do Not Place'/'Do Not Populate' reference. What language did the designer use?

Answer (score 5):

It stands for "Do Not Equip". It indicates that pads will be created for the device but that the device will not be populated during manufacturing. Instead they will be available for end user use to tweak or configure the device as appropriate.

Comment: Or the same PCB is used in several assembly, and the parts are not required in this variant.

Comment: @JayBoy The following are also used: DNP (Do Not Populate), DNA (Do Not Assemble), DNS (Do Not Stuff).  I'm sure there are ohers...

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to DNP and or DNI (do not install) but couldn't figure out the E.